# expose custom numeric type to qml

Tags: c++, qt, types, qml, customization

is it possible to expose custom numeric type(and its operators) to qml?

I want to be able to use this numeric type in qml like normal numbers ie. i want to use its +, -, <, >, and so on operators that are implemented in c++

I don't need any Q_PROPERTY or anything like that for that class - just simple

```
property Decimal foo: 10.0
property Decimal bar: 150.424 - foo
```

this class is exposed in many objects via Q_PROPERTY

writing as text(in qml) is currently working thanks to:

```cpp
QMetaType::registerConverter(&Decimal::ToQString);
```

what more can be done?

Comment: as I know to expose a custom type in QML you have to do the following: to derive the class from `QObject` and register it using `qmlRegisterType`. Is that done?

Comment: @folibis I think the main problem here would be to have the operators?

Comment: @folibis no i didn't do it yet but that wont solve the operators - and thats the main objective here to have =, -, +, *, / operators - how to force qml to use them

Comment: @folibis also i cannot derive from the QObject class as it forbids operator=  ie: compiler error: ‘Decimal& Decimal::operator=(const Decimal&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Comment: Ok, perhaps I was a bit inaccurate. If you don't want to derive from `QObject` it is not necessary but you at least must annotate your class with `Q_GADGET`. In this case you lose the option with exposing properties but as I see you don't need that.

Comment: @folibis: from what i understand, exposing type defined as Q_GADGET is not possible using this: qmlRegisterType<Decimal>("Decimal", 1, 0, "Decimal"); how would one expose it so it could be creatable from qml? via wrapper QObject class?

Comment: As I remember you can use the Q_GADGET item as a property type of another QObject-based type. But yes, all these games around `Q_GADGET` are too complicated imho.  Try also register the type using `qmlRegisterUncreatableType` but that not tested.